# fadein CSS animation issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add animation using CSS3 but I'm having some issue.
Can someone please help me?

```css
.cuv h5 {
  font-size: 25px; 
  animation: fadein 1.5s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; 
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; 


}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="cuv">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h5>Help Me</h5>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your issue. Please try with this. It would works.

```
@keyframes fadein {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```